Always got Encountered a non-categorized annotated class when upgrading Hibernate from 5.2 to 5.6
I trying to upgrade my project to use Tomcat 10.1 by upgrade my pom to use Jakarta10 and upgrade Hibernate from 5.2 to 5.6 but alway encounter this,
[http-nio-8080-exec-421] DEBUG org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl - Encountered a non-categorized annotated class [com.px.share.entity.Param]; ignoring
this causing causing this to happen next when it trying to process
ERROR com.px.share.daoimpl.GenericDaoImpl - HibernateException = org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.px.share.entity.Param
And this is happening to all of my project entity and i'm sure that all of my project entity already got @Entity and @Table so it already properly Annotated
Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1;databaseName=TOMCAT10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">P@ssw0rd</property>
        
        <property name="hibernate.id.optimizer.pooled.preferred">pooled-lo</property>
        <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.order_inserts">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.order_updates">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.connectionTimeout">60000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout">30000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.validationQuery">select 1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.testOnBorrow">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.testOnReturn">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

Here is my pom.xml
`

4.0.0
<groupId>com.px</groupId>
<artifactId>pxservice</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>pxservice</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <buildNumber>v.${project.version} build ${maven.build.timestamp}</buildNumber>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>AsposeJavaAPI</id>
        <name>Aspose Java API</name>
        <url>https://releases.aspose.com/java/repo/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-hikaricp</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>21.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.13</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20211205</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.olap4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>olap4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.20.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspose-cells</artifactId>
        <version>24.7</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspose-pdf</artifactId>
        <version>24.7</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspose-imaging</artifactId>
        <version>24.7.1</version>
        <classifier>jdk16</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspose-slides</artifactId>
        <version>24.7</version>
        <classifier>jdk16</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ar.com.fdvs</groupId>
        <artifactId>DynamicJasper</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.8</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspose-words</artifactId>
        <version>24.7</version>
        <classifier>jdk17</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspose-words</artifactId>
        <version>24.7</version>
        <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>pxservice</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                                    <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


`
Where i do wrong or where i should look into, please help me
Note: i do not have persistence.xml in my project
